# extjs 3 - Which event is fired when extjs is completely loaded

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs for my application. Which event/listener is fired when extjs completely loads the application (images and everything)?

I tried following but none of these worked:

- body or window onload (body tag is empty)
- viewport render listener

What I am doing currently: When I start the application it displays "loading" mask. Then an ajax request is fired and when it is completed, "loading" mask is removed. Following might give some idea:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.ux.mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg: "Loading..."});
    Ext.ux.mask.show();   // Show the mask

    // All components are loaded eg. viewport, tabpanel, button etc...
    ajax_request(); // Somewhere between the code ajax request is called
    // All components are loaded eg. viewport, tabpanel, button etc...

    function ajax_request() {
        // Other processing

        Ext.ux.mask.hide(); // Hide the mask
    }
});
```

The problem is the ajax request is taking much time now so i want to change the working something as follows:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.ux.mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg: "Loading..."});
    Ext.ux.mask.show();   // Show the mask

    // All components are loaded eg. viewport, tabpanel, button etc...
    ajax_request(); // Somewhere between the code ajax request is called
    // All components are loaded eg. viewport, tabpanel, button etc...

    function ajax_request() {
        // Other processing

        //Ext.ux.mask.hide();   // Hide the mask - removed
    }

    // I want to call this when everything is loaded on the page
    function everything_loaded() {
        Ext.ux.mask.hide(); // Hide the mask
    }

});
```

Any idea on this? Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: why don't you use `Ext.onReady` ?

Comment: In Ext.onReady() all the components  are loaded but they are not 100% in working state at the last statement of Ext.onReady

Comment: are you trying to load your own images and etc ? and then use ext when all component is loaded ??

Comment: @Warung Nasi 49 No i am using extjs components only. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to amol and Warung Nasi 49. Although I couldn't find the best way, I manage to get almost expected result:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.ux.mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg: "Loading..."});
    Ext.ux.mask.show();   // Show the mask

    // All components are loaded eg. viewport, tabpanel, button etc...

    setTimeout(function(){
        Ext.ux.mask.hide(); 
    }, 2000);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

What ExtJs version are you referring to? 3.x or 4.x?

If 4.x, consider using/following the [MVC Application Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture) guidelines. In that case, you want to override `Ext.application.launch` as described in [MVC Application Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture) or [Ext.app.Application](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.app.Application)

If 3.x, I guess `Ext.onReady()` is the best they have.

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated question, this is what you are looking for -

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', showSpinner, this);
    Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', hideSpinner, this);
    Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', hideSpinner, this);
...
}); //end of onReady

showSpinner = function(){
  //setup and show mask
}

hideSpinner = function(){
 //hide mask
}
```

Reference - [Ext.Ajax](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.Ajax)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I have updated my question to reflect what i want. Regards

Comment: updated answer. this also has the (good) side effect of automagically showing and hiding the mask for any ajax call while the UI is being used.

Answer (score 2):

base on your update.... i got conclusion that you are using Ext version 3.x.x

*When I start the application it displays "loading" mask. Then an ajax request is fired and **when it is completed**, "loading" mask is **removed***

how did you call the ajax ?? why don't you hide the mask in ajax callback ?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : "blabla",
    method : "GET",
    callback : function(){
        Ext.ux.mask.hide();
    }
});
```

or, mybe you want to try this [one](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?5332-preload-like-extjs.com-Api-and-examples) (this is what i used to show preload)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Currently i m hiding the mask in callback() method only but my ajax request is time consuming so i dont want to wait that long. Also, i tried the link but i can't use that coz i am using mask on body so it hides the body. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the afterlayout event and specify a method to execute when it's trigered